# How to batch convert bitmaps to SVGs?

Tags: command-line, images, conversion, svg

I have many gray scale bitmaps that I need to convert to a vector format, such as SVG. I have been using Inkscape, which gives nice results, but this takes about 10-15 minutes to open, convert, and save a file. Is there a batch or command line tool that can convert these?

Comment: you may want to have a look at `potrace` as well.

Comment: it is also possible to use inkscape as batchtool [link](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/CommandLine.html)

Answer (score 21):

#### potrace

I found this example on SO in a Q&A titled: [How to convert a JPEG image into SVG format using ImageMagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132601/how-to-convert-a-jpeg-image-into-svg-format-using-imagemagick). One of the answers suggested [`potrace`](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/).

```
$ convert input.jpg output.ppm
$ potrace -s output.ppm -o svgout.svg
```

#### Results

[image: ss #1]             [image: ss #2]

Looking at the `potrace` website you can apparently go directly from BMP to SVG.

```
$ potrace -s input.bmp -o output.svg
```

#### autotrace

Another option to `potrace` is [`autotrace`](http://autotrace.sourceforge.net/).

```
$ autotrace -output-file ouput.svg -output-format svg --color-count 4 input.bmp
```

You'll likely have to play with the `--color-count` to get an image that suites your needs.

#### Results

[image: ss #3]

#### Which to use?

Of these 2 it really depends on the source material. If you're converting images then `potrace` is likely the better option. For non-photo material such as fonts and inanimate objects such as scenery that includes things like roads, then `autotrace` with its `--centerline` switch.

> While not optimal for photos, it does good job on line art and poster-like images. Doesn't do too well with color. Autotrace has some features not available in the embedded Potrace dialog in Inkscape. For example, there is a centerline switch that is especially usefull for tracing roads (in maps) or font characters.

#### Batch conversions

You can wrap either of these commands in a for loop in Bash, which will make easy work of doing bulk conversion tasks.

```
$ for i in *.bmp; do <CONVERSION TOOL> ... "$i"; done
```

#### References

- [How to convert a JPEG image into SVG format using ImageMagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132601/how-to-convert-a-jpeg-image-into-svg-format-using-imagemagick)
- [Inkscape Wiki - Tools](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Tools)
- [Delineate - raster to SVG converter](http://delineate.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: there's no need to store an intermediate file from the JPEG. as a one-liner I used: `convert -channel RGB -compress None input.jpg bmp:- | potrace -s - -o output.svg`

Answer (score 10):

### Autotrace

You could try [autotrace](http://autotrace.sourceforge.net/index.html).

Using the following command you get the following results:

```
autotrace --output-format svg --output-file output.svg --color-count 4 imgsrc.jpg
```

I had to take a screencapture of the resulting svg and save as png to show the output.

Here is a source image jpg:

[image: skull source]

Here is the resulting image:

[image: skull convert]

Answer (score 9):

Normally, I do all my image manipulation tasks with `convert` from ImageMagic but I can't get it to play nice with svg files. You can, however, use `inkscape` itself from the command line:

```
for i in *bmp; do inkscape -f "$i" -l "$i.svg"; done
```

That will create files called `foo.bmp.svg`. To get the names right, try this:

```
for i in *bmp; do inkscape -f "$i" -l "${i%.bmp}.svg"; done
```

The problem with this approach is that, at least on my system, it pops up an annoying graphical dialog asking if I want to link or embed the image:

[image]

So, you still need to click OK manually, but it is still much much faster than doing it file by file.

The output images are identical as far as I can tell:

[image]

---

Theoretically, both [`convert`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php) and [`rsvg-convert`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/rsvg-convert.1.html) should be able to do this but I couldn't get it to work well on my images in the few minutes I spent trying. They're both worth looking into nevertheless.

Comment: I'm not positive but on the Inkscape website it says that it now has `potrace` embedded, so I wonder if it's just using that tool anyway? quote: "Potrace is now embedded into Inkscape. You don't need to run it separately." -- http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Tools

Comment: I suspect Inkscape will simply embed the bitmap image inside the SVG, hence their identical look.

Comment: @user2428118 I suspect you're right. That may or not be a problem depending on what exactly you want to do with these images.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [wiki comparsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_raster-to-vector_conversion_software) of all Bitmap-to-SVG tools. I recommend two tools based on my own testing. Both of them can convert bitmaps to SVGs in a batch manner.

1. [imagetracerjs](https://github.com/jankovicsandras/imagetracerjs) is a free js/java tool, which can vertorize the bitmaps while keeping colors.
2. [vectormagic](https://vectormagic.com/) is a commercial tool and it outperforms other tools in my testing.

[image: vectormagic]
[image: imagetracer]
[image: photepea]
[image: vertorizer]

Answer (score 1):

**`potrace`** is the tool for that. You can process them bulk, but first you have to convert the images to monochrome:

```
ls ./*.jpg | xargs -L1 -I {}  convert -monochrome {} {}.ppm
ls -1 ./*.ppm | xargs -L1 -I {} potrace {} -r 300 -b svg -o {}.svg
```

Install on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install potrace
```

If you want to convert images that are not monochrome, `Inkscape` has a tracer tool base on potrace that support multiple colors, it first converts the image to color layers and then it trace those and combines the result.

> To use the tracer, load or import an image, select it, and select the
>   **Path** > **Trace Bitmap** item, or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B.</kbd>

See

[Tutorial here!](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tutorials/tracing/tutorial-tracing.en.html)